Movie about an army of adolescents fighting, what I think they were tricked to believe were aliens?
I am trying to remember the details and I hope I am not mixing two different movies together. I am sure it is a recent movie, like within the last two years. 
There was a girl and she had a little brother. Her and her brother are supposed to get on this bus. Her brother drops the teddy bear so she misses the bus that is supposed to take them to a government base for protection. The children were supposed to leave first, then the adults. The dad goes to some meeting with the other parents to talk to the government people, who just kill everyone.
Man, I am pretty sure I am mixing it up because I also remember a guy taking care of the girl for a bit, then she makes it into the training camp where they are making the kids learn to fight whatever it is they are fighting.In short, they somehow find out that the chips the government put into their necks or brains or something was altering the way that they see everything and I think they found out that they were killing innocent people the whole time...? Ugh I am pretty sure that's how it was.

Any idea which year it was released

Oh, looking for the exact year I found it! Haha. It's 5th wave

Cool, no was not looking for exact year but tentative timeline basically anything you remember. You know every info help people to find movie.

In the 5th Wave, they have Detection Scopes. These devices overlay an x-ray when they detect an alien parasite in a person.

Except they don't really. They lie, detecting any non-tracker chipped human as an alien. The tracker chip can be held in the mouth or taped to the neck to fool the detection scope. It isn't mind control or anything. 
